# To solve large systems of multivariate polynomial equations

Tags: number-theory, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods

Nicolas Courtois et al. proposed the *eXtended Linearization*(XL) method to solve the systems of multivariate polynomial equations and analyzed the time complexity.

- Polynomial when the number of (random) equations $m \ge \epsilon n^2$, and this for all $\epsilon>0$, here $n$ is the number of variables.
- Subexponential if $m > n$ even by a small number.

But they didn't describe the size of $m$ and $n$. So my questions is that for a set of equations with the highest degree 3, how big can $m$ and $n$ be?

Reference:

Courtois N, Klimov A, Patarin J, et al. Efficient Algorithms for Solving Overdefined Systems of Multivariate Polynomial Equations[M]// Advances in Cryptology — EUROCRYPT 2000. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2000:392-407.

Answer (score 0):

- number of equations, $m$, can be arbitrarily large
- number of variables as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edit. Considering the computing capacity of modern computer, can *m* and *n* still be arbitrarily large?

Comment: @haik yes, but you will take arbitrarily large time to solve the problem

Comment: So how about within an acceptable time?

Comment: @haik to compute that, just invert their bound.

Comment: Thanks again. And I'll think it over, since my major is not math.

Comment: Excuse me. If I evaluate the complexity of XL, $D=\frac{n}{{\sqrt m}}$, and $C=({\begin{array}{*{20}c} n\\ D\\ \end{array}})^\omega$. However, this couldn't be polynomial. What does it mean?